# Заменить блок с одним классом с разным текстом на блок со своим (html)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Суть: файлов много, нужно массово заменить блок в файлах с рандомным текстом

```
<div class="test">рандомный текст</div>
```

Заменить

```
<div class="test">этом блоке на одинаковый текст во всех файлах</div>
```

По возможности в Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Ну так есть же в vs code функционал для замены в файлах в разделе "Поиск" (Ctrl+Shift+F). Ищете нужный текст и заменяете его на другой

Comment: файлов html очень много, это делать очень долго придётся, как вы пишите.

Comment: А что долгого в том, чтобы вбить в поисковую строку текст, дождаться результатов поиска, а потом в строку "заменить" вставить текст, на который вы хотите заменить старый текст, и нажать кнопку "Заменить все"? Будет произведена автоматическая замена во всех найденных файлах. P.S.: В предыдущем комментарии ошибся с горячими клавишами. Поиск по всем файлам -- (Ctrl+Shift+F), Поиск и замена -- (Ctrl+Shift+H).

Comment: Потому что в найденных будет "Найдено 1" , содержание в этих блоках разное! Вот в чём суть, мне надо будет потом выбирать другой файл и искать в нём содержание этого блока чтобы заменить...

Comment: Воспользуйтесь регулярным выражением.

Comment: @OliverPatterson верно говорит, регулярки вам в помощь

Answer (score 0):

В Visual Studio Code в строке поиска указать `<div class="test">.*</div>`, а в строке "заменить на" указать `<div class="test">этом блоке на одинаковый текст во всех файлах</div>` и активировать рядом кнопочку "Использовать регулярное выражение" (обозначена `.*`).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!